# DataBinding к собственному классу

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой
У меня есть окно с ресурсами

```
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <my:MyClass x:Key="Key" MyProperty="{Binding Path=MyProp1}" MyProp2="{Binding Path=MyProp2}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Все свойства это свойства propdp

```
public class MyClass: FrameworkElement
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    public int MyProp2
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyProp2Property); }
        set { SetValue(MyProp2Property, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProp2.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyProp2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProp2", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));        
}
```

Почему не работает привязка данных?

Comment: Почему у второго свойства owner type это typeof(MainWindow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Займёмся археологией :)

Итак, проблема на самом деле проста: `DataContext` у вашего экземпляра `MyClass` унаследован от окна, то есть это само окно (`Window` там или `MainWindow`). Но у окна-то ваших `DependencyProperty` нету, они в `MyClass`! А `Binding` идёт к окну -- непорядок.

Затем, в вашем куске кода объявлена `DependencyProperty` `MyProperty`, а `Binding` идёт к `MyProp1` -- надо исправить, а то снова не взлетит.

А ещё в объявлении `DependencyProperty` `MyProp2` ошибка -- вместо `typeof(MainWindow)` надо, конечно, `typeof(MyClass)`. Вот.

Ой, а ещё! Ваш экземпляр `MyClass` лежит в ресурсах, то есть не является частью визуального дерева. Так нельзя, ничего работать не будет. Положите его в окно. (Если надо временно скрыть, поставьте атрибут `Visibility="Collapsed"`.)